# How can I clone and sync data in between two databases in same server / hardware?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am currently using SQL Server 2008 R2 standard edition and there are two of production databases running. I would like to clone two databases in production to another in the same SQL Server with same hardware like..

1. `shopDB` (production) -> (clone & sync) `test_shopDB`
2. `productDB` (production) ->(clone & sync) `test_productDB`

I am expecting your opinions to solve this situation.

Thank you

Comment: This question is better suited for [dba.se] than here.

Answer (score 0):

I think more information on the exact scenario is going to be needed. The most simple method is probably going to be to do a backup of the production database and restore it to the second environment. You can also use replication to replicate out the tables you need to the second database.

There are a bunch of other ways you can probably do this too and they will all really depend on how much data you have to move, how often you want to sync, if the sync is going 2 ways or only 1 way etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to your scenario,

log shipping is the best option, but keep in mind that Secondary DBs will be readonly, plus connection will be periodically terminated during RESTORE phase.

Mirroring probably won't work as (as far as I remember) mirror should have same DB name + mirror cannot be used for reading if you use Standard Edition (with Enterprise you can create a readable snapshot)

Replication (snapshot or transactional) is also an option, especially when you need to copy only a set of some tables / columns, but it requires more changes and efforts to keep it working.

And of course, you can implement some custom ETL TSQL scripts - to extract delta and apply it on target DBs, but this should be done in one transaction and it may block main DBs)